# Excel summing and multiplying more rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Let's say I have the rows

```
A   | B
_______
100 | 3

50  | 2
```

I want to multiply `A * B` columns and sum the results, like: `100*3 + 50*2`;

There are a lot of rows so I cannot do it manually for every row.
But I can specify row range, for example `A1:A12`.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
=Sumproduct(A:A,B:B)
```